# Emscripten not optimizing

Tags: javascript, c++, c, emscripten

As I compile my app.cpp file into app.js using Emscripten, I'm not seeing a difference between the -o1/2/3 optimization levels when I inspect the app.js file.  They are all unoptimized/unminified and human readable.  I've run the emcc update/install commands, and I use

```
emcc -o3 app.cpp -o app.js
```

to compile into javascript.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've been through the docs and can't seem to realize what I'm passing over.  This is kind of silly to me, but I guess I just need to ask.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it was obvious.  The command is case sensitive.  Needs to be a capital 'O'.  I don't have much experience with the command line.  This is what happens.